# Switch between 10 divs but return to the first div after a few seconds on no mouse move

Tags: javascript, html

I have 9 links in my header and 10 divs in the body. The first div is the main page, the other 9 divs have diffrent content in them. What i want to do is when people mouseover the 9 links it shows the 1 of the 9 divs. But if the user stops using the mouse it needs to return to the first div after 5 minutes.

I hope somebody can help me to set this up.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Could you please post any HTML or javascript you may have written?

Comment: here is some code http://jsfiddle.net/slider2nl/Lza3c/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
// call showPage('something') to switch to a different section
var currPage = 'main';
function showPage(id) {
    if (currPage !== null) {
        document.getElementById(currPage).style.display = 'none';
    }
    currPage = id;
    document.getElementById(currPage).style.display = 'block';
}

var lastMove = new Date().getTime();
document.onmousemove = function() {
    lastMove = new Date().getTime();
}
setInterval(function() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    if (now - lastMove > 300000) {
        showPage('main');
    }
}, 5000);
```

We keep a global `lastMove` variable that gets updated with the current timestamp every time the mouse moves.

Then we have a function that's called every 5 seconds that can do something if it's been 5 minutes since the last time the mouse moved.

Comment: Updated with functionality to actually switch pages. You can see this in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/aCdRW/2/

Comment: (in the fiddle, I check every 1 second and switch back to main after 10 seconds, as opposed to checking every 5 seconds and switching back after 5 min with the numbers above)

Comment: look great going to test it out

Comment: I have tested the script and it works perfect i was wondering if i can add a fade in effect?

Comment: I would recommend using a standard library such as jQuery if you're trying to add a fade effect. For exact details, please post it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternate solution that involves setting up a new timer every time the mouse moves.

```
function goToMain() {
    // todo: switch back to Main
}
var timer = null;
document.onmousemove = function {
    if (timer !== null) clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(goToMain, 300000);
}
```

This is slightly cleaner code than my first solution, but it's doing more processing on every mouse move, so it may not be as efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can make all the divs with absolute position and just play with style.visibility switching it from "hidden" to "visible". As for 5 minutes and back to div 1 - you can make timer function and onMouseMove just reset counter.

```
<header>
<script type='text/javascript'>
     var maxTime = 300;//sec=5min
     var offTime = 0;
     document.documentElement.onmousemove = function(){offTime=0};
     function isTimeToReturn(){
         offTime++;
         if(offTime<=maxTime){
             setTimeout('isTimeToReturn',1000);
         }else{
             //change your present div to hidden and first to visible
         }
     }
     setTomeout('isTimeToReturn',1000);

</script>
</header>
```

Comment: I do not recommend incrementing an `offTime` counter every 1 second... you'll quickly get out of sync because `setTimeout(fn, 1000)` does not run exactly every 1 second, and the error will accumulate.

Comment: hmm maybe, i have never checked that, just assumed that if its on client side and its on average computer than its fairly precise.

Comment: how can i merge some of your code in my existing code? http://jsfiddle.net/slider2nl/Lza3c/8/